# Create new object by using namespace

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very strange problem to instantiate an object by using namespace.

If I try to do this, it will not work :

```
this.myView = new this.getApp().Views.SubView({ // it doesn't work
     initialize: function () {
        console.log('bouh');
     }
});
```

But, If I try to do that, it will work :

```
this.myView = new (this.getApp().Views).SubView({ // it works
     initialize: function () {
        console.log('bouh');
     }
});
```

You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/queval_j/a0yr41mn/

This kind of code has been working previously, and since the last week. I have to update my code because of this new behavior.. So, is it a problem from the JS Compiler or have I been lucky since a while ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is all about precedence 
in the failing line

```
this.myView = new this.getApp().Views.SubView({ // Doesn't work ?!
```

the new operator works on this.getApp function as the constructor, and as the constructor tries to access member '`__pages`' which is here is null , then accessing sub member '`app`' will fail

while in the working line

```
 this.myView = new(this.getApp().Views).SubView({
```

the parenthesis gives the  `this.getApp().Views` precedence over the new operator, so it is evaluated first, then return `SubView` which is then treated as the constructor by `new` operator

possible neat workaround for this is to get the value of `this.getApp().Views` in a variable like

```
 var AppViews = this.getApp().Views;
```

then use the variable directly

```
this.myView = new AppViews.SubView({
```

[jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/a0yr41mn/3/)

Comment: I understand the behavior, but why it's working like that now ?

Comment: did u tried it across different browser and got the same behavior ?

Comment: I checked what I did previously and, indeed, I was putting the parentheses.. And there is the same behavior with Firefox, Chrome and IE 11.